# How to get all combinations in PERL

Tags: perl

Suppose, i have 3 words- "i" "love" "perl". I want an array containing all possible combinations ie

```
i  
love  
perl  
i love  
i perl  
love perl  
i love perl
```

Comment: are reverse combinations allowed? e.g. "perl love i"

Comment: @MiguelPrz If "love i" is considered distinct from "i love", then you are dealing with *permutations* of the elements from a sequence, not *combinations* from a set.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the words are in @words and the result should be an array of arrays:

```
 my @words = qw(i love perl);
 my @results = ();
 for my $word (@words) {
     push @results, map [@$_, $word], @results, [];
 }
 print "@$_\n" for @results;
```

This emits the following:

```
i
i love
love
i perl
i love perl
love perl
perl
```

Each time through the outer loop, new results are added in which one of the words is added to the existing results.

To print them in the order you specified, you can sort by the number of elements in each result:

```
print "@$_\n" for sort { @$a <=> @$b } @results;
```

Comment: `push @results, map [ @$_, $word], @results, []`

Comment: @Borodin Thanks! I added your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

This is called a "power set": the set of all subsets of a set. Almost: the power set includes the empty set, which you are excluding in your requirement.

The Rosetta Code site has [a page](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Power_set) dedicated to the task of calculating  the power set in numerous programming languages, including three different solutions in Perl.

The word "combinations" usually denotes subsets of one specific size, of a set. For instance "combinations of three cards chosen from a deck of 52". The power set is built from combinations of all sizes (including empty).

Answer (score 1):

Let [`Math::Combinatorics`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Math-Combinatorics/) do the heavy lifting:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

use Math::Combinatorics;

my @words = qw(i love perl);
for my $count (1 .. @words) {
  my $comb = Math::Combinatorics->new(count => $count,
                                      data  => [@words]);
  while (my @combo = $comb->next_combination) {
    say "@combo";
  }
}
```

Then:

```
$:» perl combo.pl
love
i
perl
perl i
perl love
i love
love i perl
```

Answer (score 0):

You can view it as having three flags you toggle between 0 and 1 in every possibility. When the flag is true, the word is present in the output.

```
100
010
001
110
101
011
111
```

If you don't care about the order,

```
for my $f0 (0,1) {
for my $f1 (0,1) {
for my $f2 (0,1) {
   my @f = ( $f0, $f1, $f2 );
   my $sentence = join " ", map { $f[$_] ? $words[$_] : () } 0..$#words; 
   say $sentence if length($sentence);
}}}
```

If you want to handle an arbitrary number of words, you can use `NestedLoops`.

```
use Algorithm::NestedLoops;

my $iter = NestedLoops([ ([0,1])x@words ]);
while (my @f = $iter->()) {
   my $sentence = join " ", map { $f[$_] ? $words[$_] : () } 0..$#words; 
   say $sentence if length($sentence);
}
```